# Query Count Mysql returns 0

Tags: mysql, sql, linq

I have a question about Query using "Count" function.

I have a table : Student(id,name,age,sex)

I use sql query as:

```
Select name, age, count(id) as NumberOf
from Student
where sex = 'Boy'
group by age, name
```

And My DB:

```
1 | John  | 12 | Boy  | 
2 | Mary  | 13 | Girl |
3 | Alice | 15 | Girl |
```

I want to find a number of student is the same as age as well as boy.But it returns `Null`. I want it to return 0. How should? Thanks

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: it will return 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want this :

```
select name, age, sum(if(sex='Boy',1,0)) as NumberOf
  from student
 group by age, name;

name    age NumberOf
John    12  1
Mary    13  0
Alice   15  0
```

P.S. deliberately I put `sum` due to probability of existence of duplicated record for *name* and *age*.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without if :

```
 select name, age, sum(sex='Boy') as NumberOf
 from student
 group by age, name;
```